# Garbage Collection Annoyances - How to have a Ptr to an Obj keep the Obj alive? C#

Tags: c#, pointers, garbage-collection

I'm used to C and the use of pointers.  I know you can do a lot of stuff with pointers in C# but the garbage collection is getting annoying. Is it possible to create a pointer to the object, and somehow link the pointer to the object so that as long as the pointer is alive, the object is not cleaned up?  Something lie

```
unsafe void* Function1 () {
 SomeStruct s = new SomeStruct();
 void* ptr = (void*) &s;
 return ptr;
}

main() {
  void* p = Function1();
  p->field = 3;
}
```

When I tried to do this, the object was fine and the pointer worked inside Function1, but as soon as the function exited, the object was destroyed though the pointer was valid.  It would be awesome if there was some way to link the two as far as the garbage collector was concerned.

Comment: Why are you using pointers (more generally, `unsafe`) in the first place? Chances are you are using pointers where simple references would work. C# is not C.

Comment: btw, that sample would blow up in C as well: in C terms you're returning a pointer to a variable that was on the stack but that ceased to exist when you returned from the function.

Comment: Because 1)I like pointers, and feel they are perfectly safe if you know what you are doing, 2)I can get around a lot of annoyances in C# by using pointers. 3)It's faster often times (running-wise).   Though the main reason is that if I know two structs are the same length, and I want to access a field at a fixed location, I can't do that using an interface..

Comment: @fvu yes, you are right; I'm trying to take advantage of some aspects of C# while keeping the benefits of pointers.

Comment: If you "like pointers" why are you trying to use a language where their use is awkward and negates many of the benefits of garbage collection. If you want to use the framework and the classes therein, but still use pointers, why not use C++/CLI?

Comment: @reza, this is off topic but I assure you as a senior C# dev that pointers are almost always not required and actively harmful in C#. As you gain experience in this language you will find the same.

Comment: This question in itself shows that it's easy to do something wrong when you are using pointers... Learn to love references. They are implemented using plain pointers, so the final code is almost as fast as the best that you can do with pointers.

Comment: Your reasons are no good: 1) "When in Rome do as the Romans do" -- whether you like pointers or not, the C# way is to use references whenever reasonable. 2) I'll hazard a guess that those "annoyances" are not problems with C# or references, but with your use or understanding of them. 3) Would have to be proven on a case-by-case basis. I also seriously doubt it, as references are just pointers under the hood. And these considerations are overruled by Michael A. Jackson's Rules of Program Optimization anyway. Your main reason only makes sense if you care about struct layout. Which you shouldn't.

Comment: reza, it is not completely clear what benefits you are not getting in this case - behavior (as pointed by @fvu) is the same between C and C# in this case - both blow up when returning pointer to local object on the stack.

Comment: @usr Ok, this is the big picture.  I'm building an app that is a front end for an embedded device.  The device stores configuration information in a struct.  It then copies the memory associated with that struct to an SD card and back. Really simple, just change struct to change what is stored.  I want a similar way to access the data from the SD card.  I only want to have to define the struct, not accessor methods, to the data.  This makes it easy to keep things in sync.  I'm trying to leverage that with some benefits of objects and garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your type `SomeStruct` is not very badly named, and is in fact a `struct`, then you are allocating memory for it on the stack.

When you return from the method, the stack frame where the struct is allocated is removed, so outside the method the struct simply doesn't exist any more. There is nothing you can do do keep the garbage collector from removing it, because it's not the gabage collector that removes it. It's returning from the method that does that.

Note that a `struct` in C# is a different concept from a `struct` in C. In C# a struct is always a value type, while in C it can either be a value type or reference type depending on how you use it.

If you want to keep the value, then you can box it to keep it on the heap. You return a reference to the boxed value, not a pointer, because the garbage collector doesn't care about pointers, only references:

```
object Function1 () {
  SomeStruct s = new SomeStruct();
  // box the value:
  object o = s;
  return o;
}

main() {
  object p = Function1();
  // unbox the value:
  SomeStruct s = ((SomeStruct)p);
  s.field = 3;
}
```

You can of course pass the struct around instead of putting it on the heap:

```
SomeStruct Function1 () {
  return new SomeStruct();
}

main() {
  SomeStruct p = Function1();
  p.field = 3;
}
```

If you really need to store the `struct` on the heap, then you should consider making it a `class` instead, then it automatically ends up on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SomeStruct` is actually `struct` than it is value type and in your particular case it is allocated on stack. Note that `struct` in C and `struct` in C# have different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer that is reference-counted and stops the allocation being garbage collected until it's no longer in use is a `reference`. Use references and you are extremely unlikely to have any need for pointers or `unsafe` code at all.

C# is not C, so beware of trying to write C code - you need to learn C# and realise that there are some very large differences between the languages despite their apparent similarities.

Comment: C# references are not reference-counted.

Comment: Can I make a reference to a struct and cast it to another struct?  And C structs and C# structs are the same if you define them as LayoutKind.Explicit

Comment: @reza Assuming they are different types, no, you can't.